# Plain Kotlin module in Android Studio 3.0, `api` is not supported?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

Started in Gradle plugin 3.0 (Android Studio 3.0), the `compile` command has been replaced with `api` and `implementation`. It is explained here https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa

However, for a pure Kotlin module as below, I can't use `api`. i.e. the below code will have error when I perform a sync

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

The error is

```
Could not find method api() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-4] 
on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. Open File`
```

I have to use the 'deprecated' `compile` instead.

Why isn't `api` supported when in a pure `kotlin` module?

Comment: Do you need to explicitly expose this dependency to consuming modules?  You can use `implementation` for this.

Comment: Ya, I agree the above I could use implementation. I do have api need for other library, the above is just example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`compile` isn't deprecated in Gradle, but only in specific plugins, namely Android and [Java Library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugins. The standard [Java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) plugin hasn't made this change. Neither has the Kotlin plugin, yet. It probably will eventually (possibly after the issues described in the Java Library documentation will be solved).